# Differences in Task.init behavior in Xcode13 and Xcode14

Tags: swift, concurrency

`Task.init{}` inherits the current actor context, and asynchronous processing passed to Task would be executed in an arbitrary thread.
I was curious about this because the behavior of processing using `Task.init{}` was different when the same code was executed in Xcode13.4.1 and Xcode14.2.

The following code is an example.

```swift
import SwiftUI

class Model: ObservableObject {
    @Published var results: [Int] = [0]
    func doWork() async {
        print(" start doWork :\(Thread.isMainThread)")
        var results: [Int] = []
        for i in 0 ..< 1_000_000 {
            results.append(i)
        }
        print(" before update :\(Thread.isMainThread)")
        self.results = results
    }

    func doWork2() async {
        print(" 2 start :\(Thread.isMainThread)")
        try! await Task.sleep(nanoseconds: 2_000_000_000)
        var results: [Int] = []
        for i in 0 ..< 1_000_000 {
            results.append(i)
        }
        print(" 2 before update :\(Thread.isMainThread)")
        self.results = results
    }
}

struct ContentView: View {
    @StateObject var model = Model()

    var body: some View {

        Button.init("\(model.results.count)") {
            Task {
                print(" before doWork :\(Thread.isMainThread)")
                await model.doWork()
                print(" after doWork :\(Thread.isMainThread)")
            }
        }
    }
}
```

When the button is tapped, Task is created and processed.

[case1]
Since `ContentView` is the MainActor, I expected that the Task would inherit it and the processing in the Task would be executed in the main thread.

Xcode13.4.1 log

```
 before doWork :true
 start doWork :true
 before update :true
 after doWork :true
```

All are executed in the main thread.

Xcode14.2 log

```
 before doWork :true
 start doWork :false
 before update :false
2023-01-02 17:23:38.248216+0900 DemoSwiftConcurrencyTask[87042:10561056] [SwiftUI] Publishing changes from background threads is not allowed; make sure to publish values from the main thread (via operators like receive(on:)) on model updates.
 after doWork :true
```

doWork{} seems to be running in a background thread.
I don't trust `Thread.isMainThread`, but it does warn that `Publishing changes from background threads is not allowed`, so it must be running in a background thread.

[case2]
doWork() with `async` is a synchronous process. Try `doWork2()` with `sleep`. In this case, the log is as follows.

Xcode13.4.1 log

```
 before doWork :true
 2 start :true
 2 before update :false
2023-01-02 18:13:36.415885+0900 DemoSwiftConcurrencyTask[89588:10614813] [SwiftUI] Publishing changes from background threads is not allowed; make sure to publish values from the main thread (via operators like receive(on:)) on model updates.
 after doWork :true
```

There is no guarantee which thread you will be in after `await Task.sleep`, so  `2 before update :false`.

Xcode14.2 log

```
 before doWork :true
 2 start :false
 2 before update :false
2023-01-02 18:15:45.114962+0900 DemoSwiftConcurrencyTask[89747:10618148] [SwiftUI] Publishing changes from background threads is not allowed; make sure to publish values from the main thread (via operators like receive(on:)) on model updates.
 after doWork :true
```

From the above, I had the following thoughts about asynchronous processing (doWork()) passed to `Task.init{}`.

- Until Xcode13, it depends on the actor context of the calling point until it is suspended.
- After Xcode14, it is executed in the background.

Is this correct?

I understand that in the `doWork` process, I can use Task.detached to prevent processing in the main thread, or I can set @MainActor to specify processing in the main thread.

Comment: Xcode 14 is just more accurate, the old version just probably didn't know how to detect the issue. Put `@MainActor` on the `ObservableObject` to make sure changes happen on the `MainActor`. The new Concurrency doesn't specifically deal with threads it deals with actors. Strict Concurrency (Swift 6) will bring in a ton of new warnings and limitations

Comment: As loremipsum said, because you want your view model to publish changes on the main actor, you should either mark that published property at `@MainActor`, or mark the whole view model as `@MainActor`. And once you do this properly, the difference between Xcode 13 and 14 is immaterial. And, yes, you are correct: If `doWork` is doing something slow and synchronous, then of course you should get it off the main actor (either using `Task.detached` or, alternatively, create your own actor for this process).